New Community Tab component performance
According to the Salesforce documentation, the new tab component provides better performance.
"For the most up-to-date user experience on your Aura site, arrange your tabbed content items on the new Tab Layout component. The existing Tabs component still works, but when you replace it with Tab Layout, you and your site visitors can enjoy the new component’s better performance."
Does anyone know what "better performance" means in this case.  I have the deprecated tab component on out 150 site pages.  I will swap them out for the new component if I will gain speed improvement.  If the "performance" is something different such as easier drag-and-drop capabilities, I won't bother.

Salesforce provided the following statement indicating that the new tab component should load faster.
Why New Tab layOut component:- The Previously implemented Tab component is loading the tabs added in this component very slowly and if any custom CSS is applied on this component is also not working properly. so to enhance this component they retired the old one and introduced a new component called New Tab layout with better performance and with above features.
